# crontab not running command

Tags: linux, apple-push-notifications, cron, flock

I've been trying to run a crontab command but it isn't running for some reason.  The command is supposed to send push notifications.

My sudo crontab -e looks like this:

```
 0 0 * * 0 /home/[user]/resetWeeklyLeaderboard
 * * * * * /home/[user]/pushDelivery
```

I have a file called pushDelivery at the location above which contains the following:

```
 /usr/bin/flock -n /home/[user]/PushChatServer/push/lockfile usr/bin/php /home/[user]/PushChatServer/push/push.php development
```

I have also made pushDelivery executable by doing chmod +x pushDelivery.  This code works perfectly for my resetWeeklyLeaderboard file but won't call the pushDelivery file.

It works if I run

```
 /home/[user]/pushDelivery
```

It works if I run

```
 /usr/bin/flock -n /home/[user]/PushChatServer/push/lockfile usr/bin/php /home/[user]/PushChatServer/push/push.php development
```

However if in crontab I do

```
 * * * * * /home/[user]/pushDelivery
```

or

```
 * * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /home/[user]/PushChatServer/push/lockfile usr/bin/php /home/[user]/PushChatServer/push/push.php development
```

it doesn't work.  Please help me.  Thank you!

UPDATE:

It still doesn't work but I've tried more stuff.  I tried reversing the order in the crontab

```
 * * * * * /home/[user]/pushDelivery
 0 0 * * 0 /home/[user]/resetWeeklyLeaderboard
```

it doesn't work.  I also tried making my resetWeeklyLeaderboard code run minutely

```
 * * * * * /home/[user]/pushDelivery
 * * * * * /home/[user]/resetWeeklyLeaderboard
```

and that works for my resetWeeklyLeaderboard code but not for my pushDelivery code.  This implies to me that it is something in my pushDelivery code that is causing the issue.  However I run /home/[user]/pushDelivery from command line and it works.  What could be causing this problem?

Comment: What happens when you run `env -i  /home/[user]/pushDelivery` ?

Comment: I get the error `/usr/bin/flock: usr/bin/php: No such file or directory`  When I run `env -i /home/miguel/resetWeeklyLeaderboard` I don't get any errors.

Comment: Nevermind.  I only get `/usr/bin/flock: usr/bin/php: No such file or directory` when I run `env -i /home/[user]/pushDelivery` from the /home/[user] directory.  If I cd ../ to the top and run from there there is no error.  Curiously though if I run `env -i /home/miguel/resetWeeklyLeaderboard` I become [trueuser] where as when I run `env -i /home/miguel/pushDelivery` I stay as [user].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.  In my pushDelivery file I was supposed to write:

```
/usr/bin/flock -n /home/[user]/PushChatServer/push/lockfile /usr/bin/php /home/[user]/PushChatServer/push/push.php development
```

whereas I'd written:

```
/usr/bin/flock -n /home/[user]/PushChatServer/push/lockfile usr/bin/php /home/[user]/PushChatServer/push/push.php development
```

The "/" before the "usr/bin/php" makes all the difference.  Somehow just that slash will allow it to work outside of crontab but will fail it when run inside crontab.  I don't understand why but this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why is is not running but same thing happens to me before at that time insted of doing 
* * * * * /home/[user]/pushDelivery
try this 
*/1 * * * * /home/[user]/pushDelivery
it worked for me in this way...(both the task run in every minute)

Comment: I just tried this but it didn't work for me unfortunately. :(